# Error serializing `.a11yReport` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/audits/[id]". Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON

Tags: javascript, next.js, accessibility

I am pretty new to Next.js and the first time implementing the accessibility-checker package.

I am using getStaticProps() to request the accessibility report. Eventually, I want to move it to a button request, but I wanted to first just test the reporting feature.

However I am getting the error mentioned in the post title. The kicker is the report is getting generated in json. I can log it in the console.

In /lib/audits.js:

```
import { getCompliance, assertCompliance } from 'accessibility-checker';
...
export async function accessibilityTest(url) {

  getCompliance(url, "testLabel"+Date.now()).then((results) => {
      const data = results.report;
      console.log(data);
      return data;
  });
  
}
```

In [id].js:

```
export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
  const postData = await getPostData(params.id);
  const a11yReport = await accessibilityTest("https://www.example.com");
  console.log(a11yReport);
  return {
    props: {
      postData,
      a11yReport
    },
  };
}
```

The log in the CLI shows the report:

```
{
  results: [
    {
      ruleId: 'WCAG20_Html_HasLang',
      value: [Array],
      path: [Object],
      ruleTime: 0,
      reasonId: 'Fail_3',
      message: "Page detected as HTML, but does not have a 'lang' attribute",
      messageArgs: [],
      apiArgs: [],
      bounds: [Object],
      snippet: '<html>',
      category: 'Accessibility',
      ignored: false,
      level: 'violation'
    },
    {
      ruleId: 'WCAG20_Body_FirstASkips_Native_Host_Sematics',
      value: [Array],
      path: [Object],
      ruleTime: 0,
      reasonId: 'Fail_1',
      message: 'The page does not provide a way to quickly navigate to the main content (ARIA "main" landmark or a skip link)',
      messageArgs: [],
      apiArgs: [],
      bounds: [Object],
      snippet: '<body>',
      category: 'Accessibility',
      ignored: false,
      level: 'violation'
    },
    {...
```

But on the [id].js log it outputs undefined. I am confident it's undefined because it runs before the value returns since it's async. I am unclear how to wire this up properly to get the report in JSON that I could output in the browser.

This throws the error mentioned:

```
Server Error
Error: Error serializing `.report` returned from `getStaticProps` in "/audits/[id]".
Reason: `undefined` cannot be serialized as JSON. Please use `null` or omit this value.
```

If I change the props to:

```
report: a11yReport ?? null,
```

The error goes away, but its null when output. There is something I am not doing properly when trying to bring it back into the [id].js file. I would like to know if this is some syntax issue, or am I not tackling this in the right way.